# C# having control over HTML elements

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, dom

jQuery and JavaScript can manipulate DOM like anything. But if C# has to send something to the client, then in my knowledge, we can only user Response object to write something in the browser. Now, this would write text in the browser, but we do not have control over where would it write it. Is there anyway that we can control from C#, somehting like :

"This is the text and I want it to be innerHTML of some particular DIV"?

Comment: what are you using to generate your html? aspx? razor? do you use server side controls?

Comment: From your question, I'm assuming this is your first .net web application. Have you read any of the "getting started" tutorials? There are many and most will provide you with the basic knowledge to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways to go about doing something like this.

1. Make your div `runat="server"` and then it's accessible from the back end to manipulate
2. Register a JavaScript call using `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` and manipulate the div that way.

But also as Chuck has mentioned in his comment - that's a rather odd thing to do in ASP.NET.  For the most part you'd use Label, Literal etc. server controls to add and manipulate text on a page instead of modifying native DOM elements directly.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really how the internet works. When your browser navigates to a webpage, it sends a request to a server. The server responds with something. If it's trying to show a whole webpage, it needs the HTML of the whole page back. C# is powering the webserver.

When you browse to another page, you're not modifying an existing page; you're getting a whole new page back. We use JavaScript to get around that by letting it put out calls to webservers and use the information it gets back to modify the HTML on page, which it does know about, because it's running client-side.

So: no.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the inner html of a div from your code behind. Just ad a runat="server" attribute to the div

```
<div id="divUserInfo" runat="server"></div>
```

and in your code behind

```
string strHtml="<h3> User Name </h3><p>User description</p>";
divUserInfo.innerHtml=strHtml;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in VB.NET, but I am sure C# has an equivalent. Just inject some javascript to do what you want.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "myScript", 
    String.Format("<script>document.getElementById('{0}').innerHTML = '{1}';</script>", elementID, html))
```

Comment: Gathering information from all the comments I can say that there are either of two ways to do it  <br/>  1. Either I register a script just as you did or I decorate the control with runat= "server" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

.NET provides frameworks to do this - check out [WebForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973868.aspx) or [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3)

Answer (score 0):

[From this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Message.InnerHtml = Server.HtmlEncode("Welcome! You accessed this page at: " + DateTime.Now);
  }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>HtmlContainerControl Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <span id="Message" runat="server"></span>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want a handle on a control from the code behind it needs to have the runat attribute set to server.